# Cant transfer testnet ether

Tags: ether, parity, testnets, parity-wallet, kovan

Every time I try to transfer kovan testnet ether from one account to another it says

[-32021] Account password is invalid or account does not exist

while confirming the password for the account.
What to do?

Comment: Create a new account and make sure you never forget your password again :)